# Blogger Active LINK Class

Tags: html, css, blogger

Here is my html menu button :

```
<tr>
  <td><a href="http://exmple.com/2014/09/28.html">23</a></td>
  <td><a href="http://exmple.com/2014/09/24.html">24</a></td>
  <td><a href="http://exmple.com/2014/09/25.html">25</a></td>
</tr>
```

How to add this class on current URL?

```
 <td class="active"><a href="http://example.com/2014/09/25.html">25</a></td>
```

How can I accomplish to make this work?

Comment: $('td').click(function(){

$(this).addClass('active')

});

Comment: I don't understand what you want to say!

Comment: $('td').click(function(){
  $('td').removeClass(active);
  $(this).addCalsss(active);
});

Comment: Guys jQuery isn't tagged at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('table td a').click(function(e){
    $('table td').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent('td').addClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.active a{
    color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="http://exmple.com/2014/09/28.html">23</a></td>
        <td><a href="http://exmple.com/2014/09/24.html">24</a></td>
        <td><a href="http://exmple.com/2014/09/25.html">25</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the solution. Use it according to your needs.